# QGIS desyncing with Geoserver and Postgis

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver, postgresql

I have a setup in which the layers in QGIS get served from Geoserver from the database in postgis.

In order to avoid users inputting wrong layer, I set up some foreign keys. Users need to first create layer A, and then copy portions of layer A over to layer B. If layer B has ids that don't match with layer A, then layer B can't be saved.

Now what occasionally happens, is that sometimes, when a user creates something in layer A and then saves it, after copying it over to layer B, he can't save on layer B. Then after I check in both QGIS and in the database, the new features in layer A are NOT saved. When checking on the user's computer, it clearly shows it as saved

So I assume this is some form of desync occurring here.

I could just tell the user to restart QGIS and redraw the features but this is a time waste so I wonder if there's something else that could be done. His QGIS version is 2.14.11, would a different version solve the issue?